# when use $convert with condtions null and error the output still NaN

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I facing  a problem with aggregation in mongodb as I group the result and sum it and covert the filed to double and put on Error or On null I return `0` but the output is `NaN`.

```js
let $match= {
  $and:[{
    status:{ $in:['Completed'] }
  },{
    type:0
  }, {
    "price": { "$exists": true, "$ne": null }
  },{
    "invoice_value": {
      "$exists": true, "$ne": null
    }
  }]
};

if(Object.keys(query).length>0){
  console.log(query);
  $match.$and.push(query);
}

try {
  const res = await Order.aggregate([
    { $match },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        Prices: {
          $sum: {
            $convert:
              {
                input: '$price',
                to: 'double',
                onError: 0,
                onNull: 0
              }
          }
        },
        Invoices: {
          $sum: {
            $convert:
              {
                input: '$invoice_value',
                to: 'double',
                onError: 0,
                onNull: 0
              }
          }
        },
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }
  ])
}catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

The output:

```js
[{ 
  _id: null, 
  Prices: NaN, 
  Invoices: 834565.92, 
  count: 25211 
}]
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but I suspect this is a data problem. A number comes out for `Invoices`, but not for `Prices`, and yet the operations for the two are identical. So it probably means that at least one of your records has something in `price` that is wrong - perhaps a string instead of a number, even if it's "27", or it might be some other string value

Comment: I use the convert operator to convert the strings to numbers it works with invoices but not with prices although I handled if there's an error in converting to return zero

Comment: The condition you are handling is only one possible error :)

Comment: OnError handling if the string can not be converted and  OnNull if it's not existed or it's null field

Answer (score 0):

There is insufficient evidence in what you have provided here to solve the problem.

The calculations of `Prices` and `Invoices` are identical, so shouldn't be the problem.

The only remaining part is the data - there must be something in it that is causing it. If the data set is large, you could try running it with a smaller set to verify that your code is correct.

You can try the binary chop approach (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Take half of your data and run it. If the problem doesn't appear, it means that the problem is in the other half of the data. If it still appears, half the data again, and repeat this process until it works ok.

At the point where it starts working, you know that the problem is in the other half of the data, so go back to that and half it again. I hope this makes sense to you. It's an efficient way of working out which record is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks I found the document that causes the problem but the convert flags Error and Null should return zero if the problem happened or I implemented it wrong?

Comment: So what was causing the error? Maybe you can update your query to exclude that case?

Comment: it was a corrupted data . the field is string but can't be converted to number like '2=579'.. but I thought that onError will handle the can't convert error!!

Comment: Unfortunately things are not always as expected. That's why you get paid the big bucks :)